# How to fit res map into a long exact sequence?

Tags: group-cohomology

Let G be a finite group, H a subgroup and V a G-module. Then the embedding H in G induces a restriction map on $H^{n}(G,A)$ to $H^{n}(H,A)$. My question is that is there any long exact sequence which contains this map? And generally how to compute $H^n(G,A)$ effectively when n is small, like 0,1.

Comment: The standard technique for computing $H^n(G,A)$ when $n = 0$ is just the definition: one looks for $G$-fixed elements in $A$.  For $n = 1$,
here is a common method: the $G$-action on $A$ gives a homo. $G \to Aut(A)$; let $H$ be the kernel.  (So $H$-acts trivially on $A$.)
Then one has the inflation-restriction sequence $0 \to H^1(G/H,A)
\to H^1(G,A) \to Hom_{G/H}(H^{ab},A)$ (where the last term is written as $Hom$ rather than $H^1$ precisely because $H$ acts trivially on $A$).  Now one hopes that the outer two terms are easier to compute, and can be pieced together to understand $H^1(G,A)$. 

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence.  It's slightly more complicated than a long exact sequence, but you can extract the very concrete "inflation-restriction sequence" out of it.

Your general question is a little too general to get a good answer, though there are some good other questions on this site that you will probably find very helpful, e.g.,

[Intuition for Group Cohomology](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10879/intuition-for-group-cohomology)

[Essential theorems in group (co)homology](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12539/essential-theorems-in-group-cohomology)

If you really only want $n=0$ and $n=1$, these are very concrete and addressed in any of the standard references for group cohomology.  $H^0$ is the fixed-point functor, and $H^1$ is the group of "crossed homomorphisms" (which reduce to regular homomorphisms when the action is trivial).

Comment: Unless $H$ is normal how do you get a Hochschild-Serre s.s.?

Comment: Ah, good catch.  The way the question was phrased, it made it seem like even basic references would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

There is a long exact sequence but I think it is largely useless: We have that for any $H$-module $B$ the cohomology $H^n(H,B)$ is equal to the cohomology $H^n(G,B^G_H)$ of the induced module $B^G_H$. When $B$ is the restriction of a $G$-module $A$ we have a surjective $G$-map $A^G_H \to A$ and an injective $G$-map $A\to A^G_H$. Taking the kernel (resp.\ cokernel) we get short exact sequences of $G$-module and then the desired long exact sequence. However, the cohomology of the kernel (cokernel) seems in general at least as difficult to compute as that of $A$ and $B^G_H$.

As for the efficient computation of low degree cohomology it depends on what you mean by efficient. There are computer algebra packages that compute for reasonable sized problems but I don't think they use methods that are that far from brute computation.

Comment: Why $A^{G}_{H} \rightarrow A$ is a G-map? It seems just a H-map.

Comment: The map $A^G_H \to A$ is a little bit tricky to define (and works only because $H$ ahs finite index in $G$). It depends on the fact that the coinduced and induced modules are isomorphic, i.e., $A^G_H$ is both right and left adjoint to the restriction functor. (Think of the case of the permutation module $k[G/H]$ which has a $G$-map $k \to k[G/H]$ mapping $1$ to the sum of the elements of $G/H$ and a $G$-map $k[G/H] \to k$ mapping all the elements to $1$.)